# 10 mil perguntas de vida!

Tags: debate

Se alguém te perguntar qual a coisa mais impressionante que você fez esse ano, pode responder que você ajudou a construir um dos maiores sucessos da internet mundial. Ou quase isso. O Stack Exchange é uma rede muito grande, com sites antigos e muito bem estabelecidos em suas áreas. Comunidades que temos muito orgulho de termos ajudado a crescer. E que, agora, devemos ter muito orgulho de ver que o SOpt vem atropelando vários deles.

É sensacional ver o quão rápido nós atingimos várias marcas que costumam demorar muito mais tempo. Os primeiros 1000 usuários, 1000 perguntas, usuários com 10k de reputação. O mesmo vale para coisas que *não tivemos* mas que *teríamos* se o SOpt não fosse um projeto diferente. Nosso tamanho, crescimento, atividade e qualidade fariam com que nosso site saísse de beta público para graduação em tempo quase recorde. Se isso não é prova de que um Stack Overflow em Português foi muito bem-vindo, não sei o que é.

Vocês mereceram o site e provaram isso com o trabalho sensacional que fizeram para garantir que este seja um lugar que atende às **suas** necessidades. É isso que queremos de uma comunidade, que ela saiba, e consiga, identificar as coisas que mais precisa e crie maneiras atender a essas necessidades. Queremos que nossos sites sejam úteis e divertidos, que ensinem e que aprendam. O SOpt não só conseguiu criar sua própria personalidade, como fez dela um sucesso gigantesco.

Para todos que disseram que todos os programadores **precisam** saber falar Inglês, podemos mostrar que estamos empatados, em número de perguntas por dia, com o [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com). Um site quase 5 vezes mais antigo que o nosso, com um público maior, sobre um tema menos especializado, e ainda assim nos vendo crescer e crescer.

Uma dos meus rituais favoritos, toda semana, é visitar nossa [lista de sites da rede](http://stackexchange.com/sites) e ver como o SOpt se compara ao resto da rede. É uma excelente maneira de se obter uma perspectiva do quão bem sucedido é o site. Estamos à frente de diversos sites graduados, e antigos, em todas as métricas. Não há dúvidas de que vocês criaram uma das melhores e mais saudáveis comunidades da história do Stack Exchange.

Nunca se esqueçam de que o site é de **todos** vocês. Ele nunca vai atender à todas as expectativas de uma só pessoa. Ele vai continuar crescendo e se tornando o site que a comunidade de programação de língua portuguesa quer ter. Vocês são livres para criar, experimentar, expandir e se divertir.

Aproveitem essa marca impressionante e que venham as 20 mil perguntas!

Comment: Torço para que sirva de incentivo para outros membros brasileiros e ativos da rede SE criarem outros sites para a lingua portuguesa, como um **Ask Ubuntu**, **Server Fault**, um **Super User** entre outros. Na figuinha! =)

Answer (score 16):

Lembro-me de quando fui conversar ao vivo com o @Gabe, agora na TDC 2014 em São Paulo, e lhe disse que não lembrava desde quando usava o StackOverflow, mas tinha *"certeza que era quase desde a adolescência"*...

Foi quando ele disse: *"hehehehe Impossível! O StackOverflow tem só 6 anos de vida! :) ... Mas isso é prova de quão presente o StackOverflow está em nossas vidas, a ponto de você se esquecer de como eram as coisas antes dele!"*

Parabéns a todos os envolvidos e responsáveis pelo SOpt! Tomara que ele continue crescendo sempre, para que daqui a 6 anos, alguém de 30 anos de idade venha dizer que *sempre usou o SOpt, desde a adolescência*!

Comment: Isso quer dizer então que você tem uns 22 anos :D

Comment: E mentiu a idade pra mim! (O que já era de se esperar, de alguém tão novo...)

Comment: hehehehe Pelo que falei para o @Gabe, ou eu deveria ter 22 anos, ou o SO deveria ter 16/17 anos! ... ou ... o mais provável... eu estava *redondamente* perdido :)

Answer (score 8):

Parabéns a todos os envolvidos por esse projeto. Como sou iniciante na área, já tive muita ajuda e sempre que posso, ajudo também!
Fórum nota 10, com ótimos profissionais.

Comment: Só um detalhe: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas-%c3%a9-um-f%c3%b3rum :)