# Prepare o capelo e a beca

Tags: debate

> A graduação havia sido programada para Novembro, mas foi adiada para esperar o novo layout dos "Stack Overflows".
> [Mais detalhes aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2285/12).

No começo de Outubro o site atingiu a impressionante marca de [10 mil perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2080/12) e eu comentei sobre como o SOpt se [compara](http://stackexchange.com/sites) a outros sites da rede. Nós estamos junto com os grandes, com a diferença de que somos ainda jovens, com um brilhante futuro pela frente.

Estar entre os maiores sites da rede é um grande feito.
Estar entre o maiores feitos e ser o mais novo entre eles é um enorme feito.
**Estar à frente deles é excepcional**.
Na época o resultado ainda podia variar mas hoje eu posso confirmar que:

## O SOpt é o site mais rápido a atingir 10 mil perguntas!<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup>Depois do SOen ;)</sup>

Mais rápido que o Super User, Server Fault, Arqade, MathOverflow... Qualquer um. É uma marca impressionante e todos aqui devem estar orgulhosos da comunidade que ajudaram a construir. Talvez a maior demonstração do sucesso do SOpt, até agora. Então nada mais justo que...

## Graduar o nosso site!

Vocês merecem. Vocês construiram o maior sucesso da SE nos últimos anos. Mais especificamente, há mais de 3 anos não graduamos um site com menos de 1 ano de idade e, naquela época, as regras eram um tanto diferentes. Uma comunidade tão grande e ativa em tão pouco tempo é muito mais do que esperávamos quando abrimos o site.

O SOpt vai se tornar um membro oficial da rede, com honras e méritos.

### O que vai mudar

Parte de vocês já está farta de ouvir isto, mas o SOpt é um site diferente. Normalmente um site recebe um design próprio ao graduar mas esse não será nosso caso. Nós não só *nascemos* com o nosso design pronto como ele também é o *futuro* design do SOen. Ou seja, um dia eles vão graduar para virar nosso site :D

Além disso, a graduação eleva os requisitos para diversos privilégios. Isso significa que alguns de vocês, infelizmente, perderão certos direitos no site. É a parte menos divertida da graduação mas é um atestado de que confiamos na maturidade, dedicação e energia da comunidade e não há dúvida de que vocês vão crescer e alcançar esse novo desafio.

Com a ausência de um design e a perda de privilégios pode parecer que a graduação do SOpt é um tanto anti-climática mas ela representa muito. É a confirmação de que vocês mereciam um Stack Overflow em Português, a confirmação de que existem dezenas milhares de desenvolvedores, fora da língua Inglesa, capazes de criar uma comunidade forte. Uma comunidade que ajuda pessoas que não conseguiam obter ajuda até então.

O SOpt não é mais um "experimento", não é mais passível de previsões escabrosas sobre como ele destruiria tudo que o SOen construiu. Não é mais uma ideia arriscada, discutível.
O SOpt é uma realidade inquestionável.

Parabéns e que venham as 100 mil perguntas!

Comment: Parabéns a toda a comunidade por ajudar a construir o SOpt! E bem que eu achava que nós estávamos testando o novo design do SOen! Aliás, o nosso é tão melhor que quando eu entro no original (o que tenho feito bem menos), acho tosco.

Comment: @bfavaretto salvo alguns detalhes :) Parabéns à todos.

Comment: @bfavaretto falou bem até me fere a vista o SOen eheheh. Estamos todos de parabéns e venha lá a graduação :)

Comment: Show de bola. Parabéns para todos que ajudaram o SOpt chegar a graduação. O mais incrível, são as marcas que o SOpt atingiu. Fantástico.. Parabéns.

Comment: Um detalhe: para aqueles gringos que acharam que o SOpt seria um fiasco... \../, (o_o) ,\../

Comment: Que inveja, o @Math tem um Exchange só pra ele :/

Comment: @RodrigoBorth hahaha.. É tipo um Ask.fm só para mim! E com o selo de qualidade da SE ;-)

Comment: `10 mil perguntas!` It's over NINE THOUSAAAAAND!!1!

Comment: *BRICS, dude, the future is [BRICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BRICS)*. Parece, mas não tem nada a ver com [*u'll shit bricks*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shit+bricks).

Comment: @RodrigoBorth, o Math tá tipo arrebentando a boca do balão, a empresa teve que fazer reparos de urgência para cuidar da avalanche de visitas no perfil dele: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18494630#18494630

Comment: @brasofilo Absolutamente verdade

Comment: Já tem uma data definida pra graduação?

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Não. Mas meu palpite é semana que vem.

Comment: Show! parabéns a todos os envolvidos neste belo trabalho :)

Comment: Acredito que o SOpt é o site da rede que mais recebe "Parabéns"! ... Fazer o que?!?!?! hehehehe Parabéns a todos!!! :D

Comment: Com a graduação também teremos nosso próprio logotipo? Assim como o super user e o ask ubuntu?

Comment: @renatoargh Nós temos nosso próprio logotipo. Somos o Stack Overflow

Comment: Entendi, não haverão mudanças nesse ponto, ta certo! :)

Comment: Hail Stack Overflow PT o/

Comment: Antes não tinha o menor interesse em contribuir, não me era atrativo...e num passe de mágica, na busca por uma solução, sou recebido por algo totalmente novo à moda da casa. Nota 10!