# Por que pessoas com privilégio de editar perguntas/respostas não recebem a pontuação pelas edições?

Tags: debate, suporte, edição

Por que pessoas com privilégio de editar perguntas/respostas não recebem a pontuação pelas edições?

**Contexto:**

Antes podia angariar alguns pontinhos que me faziam rir e ficar feliz, mas agora já não os recebo (o que não me impede de editar e poder dar a minha humilde contribuição sempre que possível) e aquele sorriso se foi.

Não poderá ser desmotivador (menos incentivador)?

Comment: Particularmente acho ganhar 2 pontos por edições um exagero. Talvez fosse válido nas *tag wikis* (principal, não fragmento) e mesmo assim dependendo do tamanho. Mas acho que deveria dar pontuação sempre mesmo que fosse bem reduzido, que tenha algum limitador, alguma exigência mínima.

Comment: Exagero porquê @bigown?

Comment: Não acho exagero. Em alguns sites, é a única maneira que tenho de ganhar direito ao voto negativo (150pts). Ou de fazer um "`bootstrap` na reputação" (conceito original que dá origem aos 2pts) por outras vias que não perguntar/responder.

Comment: Oh, yes, tem uma [medalha de ouro](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor) por editar 500 posts. Serve como motivador? :p

Comment: Deveria servir, né @brasofilo? Mas pelo visto não funciona tanto; hoje, só eu, você e o bigown temos essa medalha...

Comment: Isso é coisa de amanuense e grafômano, @bfavaretto, e ao que tudo indica [pouca gente tem estômago pra isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all).

Comment: Amanuenses e grafômanos lusófonos, uni-vos! @brasofilo

Comment: Eu acho que dar 20% do que vale uma voto em uma pergunta para algo que normalmente dá uma melhoradinha mas não agrega nada novo um exagero, é minha opinião. @brasofilo a medalha não ajuda muito a não ser que ela pudesse ser recebida a cada 500 edições. Eu já estaria caminhando para a 6a :) Mas tudo isto mostra que poucas pessoas entendem o site. Aspessoas ainda acham que aqui é fórum, mesmo as que dizem que sabe que não é. Aqui é uma site colaborativo de perguntas e respostas. Tem que editar, fechar, votar negativo quando precisa, positivo quando merece e não em qualquer coisa.

Comment: Só para deixar claro: eu gostaria que sempre desse pontos por edição mas reconheço que isto só seria possível se a edição fosse moderada, ou seja, o ponto seria dado por edição aprovada. O usuário deveria passar por aprovação sempre? Isto já fica mais complicado. Não sei se teria uma solução viável. Mas um incentivo maior com medalhes é viável.

Comment: @bigown Os 20% do que vale o voto servem para apoiar a idéia de que as edições devem servir de **melhoria** para o post, não para uma "melhoradinha". A edição deveria ser o primeiro recurso em um post ruim, não o downvote ou o fechamento. Diversos posts podem ser - e já foram- *salvos* por edições, ajudando um usuário que não sabia o que fazer e aumentando a qualidade do site, de uma só vez.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suas edições agora não precisam mais de aprovação. Então se valessem os pontos, você sempre ganharia +2 por edição. Se não há como sua edição ser rejeitada, seria injusto ganhar os pontos sempre. O sistema confia que suas edições não precisam ser mais analisadas por outros usuários, mas não tanto a ponto de acreditar que suas edições *sempre* serão boas.

Mais duas coisas:

1. Existe um limite de pontos que se pode ganhar com edições (acho que são 1.000).
2. Como [o site logo será graduado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2201/prepare-o-capelo-e-a-beca?cb=1), em breve você perderá privilégios. O lado positivo é que serão precisos 2.000 pontos para poder editar qualquer postagem, e você poderá voltar a sugerir edições e ganhar mais uns pontinhos :)

Comment: "E aquele que não tem, até o que tem lhe será tirado..."

Comment: Cold, você já tá nos mil, pensando nos dois mil e dez mil. Lembra como era ter 5pts? :D

Comment: Existe alguma formula/função que descreve a queda na pontuação após a graduação do site?@brasofilo

Comment: @Cold Como assim? Quando mais pontos você tem (na verdade, quanto mais postagens), mais você tende a ganhar na inércia, por meio de votos que vão "pingando" ao longo do tempo.

Comment: Pelo que entendi após a graduação para SOpt(sem beta :)) alguns privilégios serão perdidos certo? E achei que seria feito mediante a redução na pontuação?

Comment: Não, ninguém perde pontos, @Cold. Os privilégios é que passam a ser mais "caros".

Comment: @Cold, dá um confere na tab `Privileges` no seu perfil do [so] (p.ex.), lá tem os valores para os privilégios de um site graduado.

Comment: Ta esclarecidíssmo. Vlw malta (@brasofilo obgdo pela recordação da minha conta no SOen :)).

Comment: @brasofilo O SOen não é um bom parâmetro, como ele é muito grande ele tem "preços" de privilégios mais caros. É melhor ver qualquer (acho eu) outro site da rede.

Comment: @Cold, vide comentário do bigown acima.

Comment: @bigown qualquer site graduado tem o mesmo "preço" dos privilégios. Olha o [meu SE](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges) por exemplo :P

Comment: @Math hoje até diminuiu as diferenças mas o SOen ainda tem exceção. Dê uma conferida.

Comment: @bigown Então, olhei um por um e a única diferença que eu percebi é o privilégio de criar tags, que no SOen é de 1500 enquanto nos demais é de 300