# Sobre a graduação

Tags: debate

O dia em que escreverem a história do SOpt, vão provavelmente batizá-la de "De promessas, o inferno está cheio" (Ryan Gosling vai fazer meu papel no filme).

Conforme o [prometido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2201/12), o SOpt estava sendo programadado para graduar segunda-feira passada, dia 24/11/2014. Mas entre o anúncio e a data programada houve a [atualização do design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277200/9835) do SO com a versão final do que nosso layout começou.

Então entramos no dilema de graduar o site com o design atual e alterá-lo mais pra frente ou segurar a graduação para que ambos aconteçam juntos e o SOpt possa ganhar um singelo presente de graduação.

Decidimos esperar. Dessa maneira os 2 "Stack Overflows" se tornam irmão gêmeos oficiais!
Não temos certeza de *quando* o novo layout vai ficar pronto, mas ele já está sendo publicamente testado e não deve demorar muito. Mais algumas poucas semanas (nada de 6-8 dessa vez).

Sinto muito adiar ainda mais a graduação, mas é por uma boa causa.

Comment: E as camisetas? :)

Comment: @Math Vão ser enviadas esse mês. Vou enviar a lista para o fornecedor hoje ;)

Comment: A atualização do design foi uma barafunda :D

Comment: -1 por "Decidimos esperar. Dessa maneira os 2 "Stack Overflows" se tornam irmão gêmeos oficiais!"

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu não sei o que "barafunda" significa, mas se for algo bom, eu concordo. Se for ruim, eu discordo. ;D

Comment: @Gabe barafunda quer dizer "trapalhada, confusão". Só comentários e problemas a choverem por todos os lados naquele post.

Comment: @JorgeB. A idéia de abrir o post é justamente usar dezenas de milhares de olhos para encontrar os problemas, ué. Reclamações e comentários são esperados e bem-vindos.

Comment: @Gabe com "barafunda" não quero dizer que seja uma critica, só um comentário, entende?

Comment: @JorgeB. Entendi. Qualquer pedido de feedback aberto pra tanta gente vira uma desordem mesmo

Comment: Com um bocado de jeito chego aos 3k antes da graduação :)

Comment: Antes de o novo design ir pro ar, seria legal consertar o [bug teimoso](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/454/sprites-cortados-ou-deslocados-em-telas-com-dpi-alto) que resolveu reaparecer no meta.

Comment: @bfavaretto O Jin já consertou, desconsertou e revisou isso umas 3 vezes. Da última vez ele disse que ia dar jeito, se bem me lembro. O único jeito de saber se vai consertar no main e no meta é avisá-lo e esperar o layout sem aplicado em ambos. Vou comentar com ele.

Comment: Ficou consertado durante quase todo o mês de novembro. Semana passada pifou de novo (só no meta). FJI (for Jin's information, hehe).

Comment: @bfavaretto Ou seja, não faz sentido nenhum. Acho que o único jeito de consertar isso é tirar o site do ar. Vou avisar todo mundo que a culpa é sua

Comment: Outra solução é queimarmos todos os aparelhos com tela de alta densidade.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eles **obviamente** estão possuidos, e não conheço nada melhor para lidar com o sobrenatural que uma bela fogueira

Comment: Ahahahah vocês são um espetáculo

Comment: Sem querer ser chato mas tem previsão de quando deve começar a enviar as camisetas? Não estou querendo te apresar, só estou preocupado pois do dia 20/12 ao dia 05/01 não terá ninguém em casa, então na verdade estou querendo mais é que atrase, rs

Comment: @Math Eu não tive tempo de lidar com a lista nas duas últimas semanas. Entre o tempo de fabricação, envio e translado - considerando o atraso normal de Natal - eu não acho que você vai perder nada :D

Comment: O "beta" vai ficar ao lado do nome da comunidade na página principal até quando?

Comment: @Victor Até o site graduar, quando sair o layout novo.

Comment: E há alguma previsão de quando isso vai acontecer?

Comment: @Victor Tudo que eu sei é "daqui há algumas semanas". A equipe de design tá trabalhando no layou, ele já está sendo testado no Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9):

Antes de mais, os parabéns por mais um excelente trabalho que tem vindo a ser realizado pela Stack Exchange para a comunidade!

[image: A euforia do utilizadores ao verem a SE a entrar em palco!]

<sup>Créditos da imagem para [CMSeter](http://www.freeimages.com/photo/933791).</sup>

Eu, e certamente todos nós, agradecemos a oportunidade dada de termos um lugar onde podemos partilhar o conhecimento e aprender uns com os outros na nossa língua materna.

Quero aproveitar esta ocasião para deixar um ponto de reflexão sobre algumas coisas que tenho observado, de facto, apenas 2 assuntos mais destacados:

## Camisetas / T-shirts

Pessoal, o Gabe♦ e a SE estão a oferecer-vos algo, honestamente, estarem constantemente quer por email quer por comentários em diversas perguntas a questionar ambos sobre a chegada da oferta só tem vindo a trazer ruído quer no email quer no site:

Exemplo do que tenho visto:

> user1: Sim, podes somar 2+2 que o resultado vai ser 22!
> user2: Ahhh ok, não sabia disso nessa forma.
> user3: A camiseta, já chegou a vocês?
> user2: Não, ainda não recebi @Gabe
> user1: É, também podes elevar o `2` para obter o mesmo resultado.
> Gabe♦: As camisetas estão quase a ser enviadas, mais uma semana.

Aproveitei que estava a escrever sobre isto e criei uma pergunta aqui no Meta que podem favoritar para serem notificados sempre que alguma novidade seja postada:

[**Camisetas / T-shirts 2014**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2348/223)

Sendo única e exclusivamente sobre as Camisetas de 2014, não existe o problema de estarmos a falar sobre um assunto e pelo meio surgir a questão das camisetas! Ali o assunto É camisetas :)

## Graduação

Pessoalmente, entendo que a SE tenha todo o direito de gerir da forma mais conveniente a graduação do SOpt, mas estar constantemente a prometer ou a impor uma data que leva ao entusiasmo e expectativa dos utilizadores só para depois ser adiada por X semanas, acabam por obter o efeito contrário ao desejado.

Todos sabemos que este site é novidade, e de certa forma único pelo facto de estar internacionalizado, é normal que as coisas ainda andem aos tombos, mas preferia ouvir dizer:

> Pessoal, estamos a magicar a graduação do site!

Do que andar constantemente a ouvir que a graduação vai ser daqui a X tempo.

Só neste tópico existem semanas e semanas entre a data do tópico que refere uma promessa anterior ao mesmo, e as datas nos comentários, para não falar que à data de hoje, mais semanas passaram...

Em suma, Gabe♦, pessoalmente, preferia não ter datas da "vossa" parte para não acordar com o coração destroçado ;)

[image: Broken Heart]

<sup>broken heart by [fastreflex](http://fastreflex.deviantart.com/art/broken-heart-120730729)</sup>

Comment: "estar constantemente a prometer ou a impor uma data que leva ao entusiasmo e expectativa dos utilizadores só para depois ser adiada por X semanas, acabam por obter o efeito contrário ao desejado." - e já não é a primeira vez, sobre este ou outros assuntos... (`+1`)

Comment: A graduação foi planejada para Novembro, e adiada (com uma previsão de 'semanas'). Nunca foi marcada outra data além dessa. Como qualquer outro site da rede, a graduação do SOpt está esperando o design. De novo, nunca foi marcada **outra** data para a graduação. Ela vai acontecer quando o layout ficar pronto.