# Camisetas / T-shirts 2014

Tags: debate, camisetas

Tenho observado nos mais diversos lugares uma constante tentativa de ser apurado quando chegam as famosas camisetas que o nosso MC referiu:

[image: Camiseta]

<sup>(c) [Tshirt Factory](http://www.tshirt-factory.com/)</sup>

Estou a abrir esta pergunta para que se possa ter um lugar específico para questionar sobre o assunto, a possibilidade de favoritar a pergunta e receber notificação sempre que alguma novidade é "postada" bem como receber uma resposta do Gabe♦ assim que as ditas tenham sido expedidas!

Até criei uma tag ↴

Comment: Eu já recebi a minha!

Comment: Como compro uma camiseta dessa?

Comment: Terá novamente essas camisetas?

Answer (score 14):

Parece que já estão a ser entregues e recebidas (a minha já chegou):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fica então a foto :)
Para Portugal, Figueira da Foz

Comment: A minha chegou ontem à tarde. Thx Gabe♦!

Comment: Olha como é que chegou? Encomenda a levantar nos CTT? Vais levar na cabeça por causa do mail, o @Gabe já pediu para não acordarem aquele email.

Comment: @JorgeB. A minha veio via CTT, entregue em casa.

Comment: @ramaral eu nunca estou em casa...

Comment: Já agora @ramaral e CesarMiguel e encontro SOpt em Portugal?

Comment: Nesse caso o carteiro deixa o aviso e terás de levantá-la nos correios.

Comment: @JorgeB. chegou pelos CTT ;) em relação ao jantar tenho de ver ainda. Por vezes tenho de trabalhar durante o fim de semana e fica complicado :s

Comment: @JorgeB. Em relação ao encontro, o meu problema é ser em Braga, se for mais perto do centro do país podem contar comigo. Estou desempregado, não me posso dar ao luxo de ir jantar a Braga

Comment: @ramaral podes dar sugestões, vê no tópico, tem lá já sugestões de sítios.

Comment: O logotipo está errado :)

Comment: @bigown Tem razão, bigeye

Comment: É o logotipo novo, não @bigown?

Comment: @bfavaretto pode ser. Mas eu esperaria o que nós usamos para diferenciar.

Comment: Alguém no Brasil recebeu?

Comment: @bfavaretto é o logotipo novo, mas sem o verdinho em baixo, acho que foi isso que ele quis dizer

Comment: Aguardando a minha chegar... Acho que vai demorar pra chegar aqui, correios tem mais dias de greve do que de trabalho.

Comment: Encomendas ficam meses nos CDC. Vide as muambas que compramos da china.

Comment: A minha também já chegou, estava na caixa de correio, obrigado @Gabe e obrigado StackoverflowEmPortuguês :)

Comment: A minha acabou de chegar! Muito obrigado @Gabe! :)

Comment: poxa... queria comprar uma.. :(

Comment: Sou um membro recente e gostaria de saber como adquirir uma camisa dessas

Answer (score 11):

Finalmente chegou! @Gabe muito obrigado, o adesivo ficou muito legal no meu notebook!
Serio mesmo, deem uma olhada em como ele se encaixa perfeitamente no layout do note.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ah, a camisa também ficou legal :P
hehehe

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom, brincadiras a parte, muito obrigado a todos que ajudaram a construir essa comunidade incrivel que é a SO-pt, depois de ressucitarem o e-mail mais do que o Sam e o Dean em sobrenatural resolveram se acalmar kkkk. E olha que coincidencia, chegou justamente quando eu terminava de postar uma pergunta no SO-pt :P

Comment: Um dia eu ganho uma :(

Answer (score 11):

Aqui esta a prometida foto da *t-shirt* do SOPT por Londres =).

[image: Deal with it]

Answer (score 9):

Chegou ao Rio de Janeiro o/, quase joguei o adesivo fora junto com a embalagem, sorte que acessei aqui antes e vi que o RodrigoBorth colou no notebook. Muito bom!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ainda há esperança então :)

Comment: Eu joguei o adesivo fora com a embalagem!!! Só percebi que tinha adesivo quando vi a resposta do RodrigoBorth aqui :(

Comment: Ainda não foi hoje (rs), mas a esperança é a última que morre (tomara).

Comment: @bfavaretto, pelo tempo da entrega, é mais fácil pegar a arte e mandar imprimir um adesivo novo... Pensando bem se a minha não vier vou fazer um silk - o azarão da turma :(

Comment: Eu quase joguei o adesivo fora também. Quando pensei em olhar a embalagem novamente. :D

Answer (score 8):

Demorou mas chegou, como disse, a esperança é a última que morre... :)

Chegou ontem, mas só deu pra postar hoje. Bati a foto assim que abri, e só agora que reparei que não saiu "em português".

Mais um bem vestido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 8):

Senhores, eu gostaria apenas agradecer pela camiseta + adesivo! :D
Vocês são fodas!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]